# Why Azure devops eqality condition evaluates to false rather than true?

Tags: azure-pipelines

This is what I have in my main `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

```
parameters:
  - name: buildType
    displayName: Select the build Type
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - qa
      - uat
      - prod

variables:
  - name: isDevBuild
    value: eq('${{ parameters.buildType }}', 'dev')
  - name: isQABuild
    value: eq('${{ parameters.buildType }}', 'qa')
  - name: isUATBuild
    value: eq('${{ parameters.buildType }}', 'uat')
  - name: isProdBuild
    value: or(
      eq('${{ parameters.buildType }}', 'prod'),
      eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'),
      eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
      )
```

I have the following lines in two separate files responsible for building the project for iOS and Android. This is the script for building the project for Android.

```
steps:
...

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Build for Android (Dev Debug)
    condition: eq(variables.isDevBuild, 'true')
    inputs:
      script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build apk --debug --build-number=$(Build.BuildId) --target=lib/main_dev.dart'
      workingDirectory: '$(projectDirectory)'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Build for Android (Prod)
    condition: eq(variables.isProdBuild, 'true')
    inputs:
      script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build apk --build-number=$(Build.BuildId) --target=lib/main_prod.dart'
      workingDirectory: '$(projectDirectory)'
```

The above tasks skip by the pipeline. It makes sense for the second task but not for the first task. This is the output of this task:

```
Evaluating: eq(variables['isDevBuild'], 'true')
Expanded: eq('eq(''dev'', ''dev'')', 'true')
Result: False
```

I expect the result should be `true` but it is `false`. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Those doubled quotes in the Expanded line look odd; have you tried defining the isDevBuild variable without the quotes e.g. `eq(${{ parameters.buildType }}, dev)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable expansion message is telling you the problem.

`eq('${{ parameters.buildType }}', 'dev')` is not the correct syntax. `${{}}` tells the YAML compiler to treat everything in there as a compile-time expression. You are providing the literal text `eq('result of compile-time expression', 'dev')`, not the results of *evaluating* that statement.

All this to say:

1. Please review the documentation for Azure Pipelines, as it provides dozens of examples.
2. Move the entire statement inside `${{ }}`:

`${{ eq(parameters.buildType, 'dev') }}`

Comment: Thank you Daniel. You are absolutly right. I could guess what is the reason of inequality from the log but I couldn't figureout what is the issue even after comparing my code with samples in "Specify conditions" doc. Your explanation helped me to underestand `${{ }}` better. Thanks again.